# Relative Server-side include and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, server-side-includes

I have an ASP.NET MVC Web application that needs to include several other html files using the include directive, like so:

```
<!--#include virtual=/include/bottom.shtml -->
```

My problem is that I will need to deploy this application on servers where the application path will differ. For example, in one place I might have the application mapped on, say, `localhost/myapp/` and in another I might have just `localhost/`.

In the `localhost/` scenario, the code example I gave above works just fine. But when my app is on `localhost/myapp`, I get a parser error message which lets me know it could not find the file.

How can I customize the directive to take into account the relative path of the application (preferably without using find and replace every time) ?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kill the leading slash -- that is forcing the path to calculate from the root, not your page.

But like @mare said, there is no reason to be using a #include in 2011. What you probably want to do is render it as a partial using Razor's `@Html.Partial()`.

---

Given the updated constraints, there is still a much cleaner way to handle this in MVC than using the old #include. What you want to do is setup a controller action to read the file off disk and spit back the content. Then render that action like a normal MVC action.

Comment: I can't use the Razor view engine, I need to stick to the ASP engine. I also need to include those exact HTML files, can't change the format. As far as I know, Html.Partial() needs a view name and it won't accept .shtml (nor html) files. Also, killing the leading slash will make it search in my Views/Shared folder.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect the new constraints.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I don't know why you would be using such directives in ASP.NET MVC, because there are now other better options such as Partials, Sections, etc.

However, if you really do want to use those directives, you can get the relative paths using the `Url` helper methods, such as `Url.Content()`, `Url.Action()`, and `Url.ActionLink()` to construct links in ASP.NET MVC.

For example, this would render a relative path to the `bottom.shtml` file in a typical ASP.NET MVC Razor view:

```
#include virtual=@Url.Content("~/include/bottom.shtml")
```

Now your problems stem from using an `include`, which is apparently inside an HTML comment. I can only explain my observations. If I do this in my View:

```
<!-- @Url.Content("~/public/images/foobar.png") -->
```

And this for ASP.NET MVC WebForms view engine:

```
<!-- <%=Url.Content("~/public/images/foobar.png")%> -->
```

I get this rendered by the browser in source of the web page by both previous sentences:

```
<!-- /public/images/foobar.png -->
```

As such, I believe it is working.

Comment: actually, now I figured, I don't know whether this will get parsed by the server, since it's in HTML comments, you might want to try it out

Comment: The result of what you suggest is an html comment in my parsed page which looks like so: <!--#include virtual=/include/bottom.shtml -->. No actual including happens.

Comment: How would that be an include directive, then ?

Comment: I seem to have to provide a link to the server-side include syntax: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Side_Includes#Basic_syntax which is something you should know before you answer to this type of question. Therefore, please review your answer into making it a more constructive one.

Comment: There is no need for name calling and assumptions about either existent or nonexistent knowledge on the topic. I asked a clear question and did not force anybody to answer. My problem was (and still is) the fact that I can't include a relative path in the server-side include that I HAVE to use. Your suggestion to use `#include virtual=@Url.Content("~/include/bottom.shtml")` does not help me, as the server does not see this as a server-side include statement.

Comment: maybe you should check my revised answer coz I posted new samples inside the HTML comments, which work perfectly at my side

Comment: I'm sorry, but it doesn't work. Here is what I tried: 1. `#include virtual=<%= Url.Content("~/include/bottom.shtml") %>` which outputs exactly `#include virtual=/include/bottom.shtml`; 2. `<!-- #include virtual=<%= Url.Content("~/include/bottom.shtml") %> -->` which only outputs the commented include, _not_ the html I want. What should be output is the content of the `bottom.shtml` file : the code `<!--#include virtual=/include/bottom.shtml -->` outputs exactly what it should, but this path is not relative. Is this more clear ? Should I provide links to sample code ?

Comment: what's in those .html files? If you can change the extensions to .cshtml, then you can easily render out any HTML that might be inside via Html.RenderPartial() or Html.Partial(), just tried that out. However, it won't take .html because it says there is no view engine to render that extension. Can you try it out?

Comment: I'm restricted to using the Web Forms View Engine, so if I change the extension, I'll get the same error with no view engine to render it. Changing it to .aspx makes another error pop up, which says that the web page must derive from ViewPage. I have all these restrictions because other people will need to edit or switch or add other .shtml files. Also, this MVC application was coded before Razor came out and it's large enough so that I can't even dream to switch it all to Razor in a moderate amount of time.

Comment: Once again I forgot you are on WebForms view engine. In that case, you don't change it to .aspx (that would mean it is its own page in entirety) but change it to .ascx. Then add the T4MVC to the project and you will be able to do this <%=Html.Partial(MVC.Shared.includes.bottom) %>

Comment: BTW whoever introduced includes into this application made a very poor decision and this decision should be recalled/corrected as soon as possible. Mistakes like that should be pointed out.